# Autocomplete suggestions for available bucket keys of terms aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

At UI I need to show the autocomplete suggestions which gives me the terms containing the searched term. e.g. if I search `per` I may get suggestions as `Peru`, `Perry`, `Casper`, `Naperville`, `Cooperstown` etc.
The search box is to search/filter on a filed which is being used/shown as the terms aggregation for cities. This field type is array, so one document can have multiple cities. The auto-suggestions should only have the cities from available/resulted documents.

I am aware to use the filter Feature of terms aggregation with the proper regex.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_4

But I am looking for a better solution available in elasticsearch which can provide me the fastest results.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to use `wildcard field` new keyword data type introduced by Elasticsearch. For more information check official documentation of Elastic about wildcard field [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type). This keyword field type is optimized for wildcard query.

Comment: Can "wildcard" field be used in the terms aggregation with include. I could not find that in the referred documentation?

Comment: It should be OK to use.

Comment: Thanks @Kavesh. We are still on ES 6.8, so wouldn't be able to make use of this

Comment: Your option if you don't want to upgrade to ES 7.X would be to use N-gram token filter to generate all terms for better performance on ES. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't aware to use the `terms` aggregation. It's the easiest way to solve you problem

Mapping

```
PUT /autocomplete_suggestions
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "lowercase_tokenizer": {
                    "tokenizer": "lowercase"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "city": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "lowercase_tokenizer",
                "fielddata": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Documents

```
PUT /autocomplete_suggestions/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"city":["Perry","Moscow"]}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"city":["Casper","Cooperstown"]}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"city":["Vologda","Kostroma"]}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"city":["Naperville","Penza"]}
```

Aggregation query

```
GET /autocomplete_suggestions/_search?filter_path=aggregations.by_city.buckets.key
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "city": {
                "value": "*per*"
            }
        }
    }, 
    "aggs": {
        "by_city": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "city",
                "include": ".*per.*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "by_city" : {
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "casper"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "cooperstown"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "naperville"
                },
                {
                    "key" : "perry"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The `wildcard` query is optional. It speed up the entire aggregation query. You can use `ngrams` instead of wildcard